# keep getting function location from ipywidget dropdown menue when I want to save as df

Tags: python, function, ipywidgets

I am trying to make a simple password generator using dropdown from `ipywidgets` but when I try to put answer in a DataFrame in order to save in a CSV file, it keeps giving me the function's memory location.

```
import ipywidgets
import pandas as pd
import string
import random
import csv


#get user input for username and website name
website_name = input("Please enter the website name: ")
user_name = input("Please enter your username: ")

#define dropdown menue
drop_down = ipywidgets.Dropdown(options=list(range(15, 21)),
                                value=20,
                                description='Number:',
                                disabled=False,
                                )

#function to generate random password
def Generate_password(length):
    import string
    import random
    password_choices = string.ascii_letters + '1234567890' + '!@#$%^&*()_-+'
    password = [random.choice(password_choices) for _ in range(length)]
    return "".join(password)
    a= "".join(password)
    
    

print(str(a))

#get answer in form of DataFrame
final = {website_name: [user_name, (ipywidgets.interact(Generate_password, length = drop_down))]}
final = pd.DataFrame(final)
print(final)

#save to csv
final.to_csv('pass_list.csv')
```

This is the result I get:

```
Please enter the website name: Yahoo
Please enter your username: ABCDEFG
<function Generate_password at 0x0000013ED6F3FD38>

Number:

'%H91e(Mnh5HQqpLsZSPd'

                                               Yahoo
0                                            ABCDEFG
1  <function Generate_password at 0x0000013ED6F3F...
```

Instead of `<function Generate_password at 0x0000013ED6F3FD38>` in my DataFrame I want `%H91e(Mnh5HQqpLsZSPd` to show up. What can I do?

Comment: Edit:instead of <function Generate_password at 0x0000013ED6F3F... i want the password to show

Answer (score 0):

You don't need interact, just call the function.

```
pw = Generate_password(drop_down.value)
final = {website_name: [user_name, pw]}
final = pd.DataFrame(final)
```

Also you should delete a= ... after the return. It does nothing and may be confusing.